# AES Encryption with PHP

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I am very new to PHP and have now come across encryption with PHP. I have created the PHP file to generate a key using AES and got it working but now very stuck on creating a PHP file that will do the following:

- Store a generated key
- Encrypt the following plaintext data:   *Fido!hcteF^
- Decrypt the encrypted data
- Output all the following to the webpage:
  the key
  the plaintext data
  the encrypted data
  the decrypted data

I Know I need to add the follow code

**The encryption function**

```
function encryptData($data, $key) {
// remove the base64 encoding from our key so we again have the 256 bit key
$encryption_key = base64_decode($key);

// generate an IV
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));

// encrypt the data using CBC mode AES 256 encryption, also using the encryption key and IV.
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);

// The $iv is need along with the key for decrypting, so keep it with our encrypted data using a unique separator (::)
return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}
```

and

**The decryption function**

```
function decryptData($data, $key) {
    
// remove the base64 encoding from our key so we again have the 256 bit key
$encryption_key = base64_decode($key);

// split the encrypted data from our IV - our unique separator used was "::"
list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2);

// use the encrypted data, the key and the IV to return the plaintext data
return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
}
```

Thank you for any help it is very much appreciated

Comment: if its a single key, then you can define in CONSTANT, else you need to store in DB or somewhere you store the encrypted data.

Comment: “ I have created the PHP file to generate a key”, please show that, and explain, per your first bullet, what problems you are facing with “storing it”.

Comment: HI Chris thank you please see generated Key when I enter all the code for storing a generted key and the other files nothing shows up                                                               <?php
$encryption_key_256bit = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
echo $encryption_key_256bit;
?>